# Overwrite the master branch with the remote branch master

Tags: git

I've made modifications on my master branch, but I would like to pull the remote master branch and delete the content on my current master branch (overwrite). Could anyone be able to tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a `pull`, which is `fetch` + `merge`:

```
git pull origin master
```

Merging the remote `origin`'s `master` branch into the current local branch.

For `rebase`-ing (instead of `merge`-ing), use `--rebase`:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Comment: I have two error : `error: Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: Additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes.`, but I don't really care about that. Could you help me with that

Comment: @DavidHilbert Why don't you just delete the branch then: `git branch --delete <whatever>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
git reset --hard HEAD       # DESTRUCTIVE. Deletes all uncommitted changes.
git checkout origin/master  # will print a warning 'detached head'.
git branch -D master        # 'kinda' destructive for locally committed changes
git checkout -b master      # recreates a local master branch
git branch --track origin/master  # restores tracking from 'origin' remote
```